# -bash: ource: command not found

Tags: bash

There is this ONE machine at work that always has a problem.  It is all messed up.  But one thing I thought I could fix was seeing this error ...

```
-bash: ource: command not found
```

... as soon as I ssh on to the host.  It also happens if I `su` to another user ... as in:

```
$ sudo su -
Last login: Fri Dec  9 22:57:32 UTC 2022 on pts/1
-bash: ource: command not found
```

I looked at the `/etc/profile` and the `/etc/bashrc` and I do not see the string "ource" anywhere in them.  Where else should I look?  Is there something like `set -x` I can set to debug login scripts?

Comment: The files in /etc are generic versions. Each user also has hidden versions in their home directories. I have `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`. Check those too. Almost certainly there is a bad edit, and that word should be `source`.

Comment: ah! It was a script in the /etc/profile.d directory.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457888/how-to-find-all-locations-where-path-is-set/457903

Comment: @RedCricket As the issue has been resolved, will you write an answer or will you delete the question? Alternatively, we can delete the question.

Comment: Also remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in the this system's `/etc/profile.d` directory there where many (around 20) different scripts and one of them had a typo of `ource`.  I fixed the typo (changed the string to `source`) and the problem was corrected.